# What does "Could not perform operation (update slice window)." mean in CellTracker for Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I recently downloaded the cell tracker software for [Matlab](http://celltracker.website/download.html). When trying to load an image file (a stack of 109 tiff images), an empty image box pops up with the error

> "Could not perform operation (update slice window)."

Does anyone know what this means or how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: CellTracker accepts TIFF, AVI, and BioFormats files. The image file must contain at least two frames in order to perform tracking.

Answer (score 0):

In ImageJ I converted the TIFF stack to grayscale (Image > Type > 8-bit, 16-bit, or 32-bit; just not RGB Color) and that fixed the error!